# How to handle ODbl When using this URL :http://www.overpass-api.de/api/interpreter

Tags: ios, openstreetmap, overpass-api

The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL.

Error: encoding error: Your input contains only whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

The term **ODbL** refers to the Open Database License, e.g. legal terms describing what you may do with the downloaded OSM data in your app, how to correctly attribute the use of OpenStreetMap data, to name a few.

Please see https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright for details.